# Unrecognized command while using tikzpicture in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

While compiling pyramid figure, an unrecognized command popup?
What is the reason and how can it can be solved?

pleas, see pic belew:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
\tikzset{tri/.style={%
                        regular polygon,
                        regular polygon sides=3, %% For fun, vary this number at will
                        minimum size=#1,
                        draw,
                        thick,
                        anchor=north
                    },
                    ptext/.style={font=\bfseries,align=center,text width=0.8*\pyrsize}
        }

    \NewDocumentCommand{\pyramid}{sO{}mm}{% #3 size; #4 entries
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\incrrate}{0.80}% The rate at which the triangles decrease in size
        \coordinate (T) at (0,0);
        \foreach \test/\testi [count=\testnum from 1] in {#4}{\xdef\tot{\testnum}}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\incr}{#3/\tot}
        \foreach \step/\col [count=\stepnum from 0] in {#4}{%
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\pyrsize}{#3-\incrrate*\stepnum*\incr}
            \node[tri=\pyrsize,fill=\col] (T\stepnum) at (T) {};
            \ifnum\stepnum=\numexpr\tot-1\relax
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\lift}{0.0*\incr*\incrrate}% raise text in top shape
            \else
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\lift}{0.1*\incr*\incrrate}% raise text in remaining shapes
            \fi
            \node[above=\lift of T\stepnum.south,ptext] {\step\strut};
        }%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
    
    \pyramid{3.0in}{Inner control/green, Primery Control/olive, Secondary control/yellow, Tertiary\\control/orange}

\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you expect your editor to know every macro that you make? Your title does not really suit what you are describing. Unless you get an error from this code your problem only seems to be the syntax highlight in your editor. And you make no mention of the editor you use (latex has nothing to do with syntax highlighting, that is an editor thing)

Comment: Hi, Acctialy I am using TeXstudio 4.0.1 (git 4.0.1)
Using Qt Version 6.2.0, compiled with Qt 6.2.0 R

Comment: What do you mean 'pops up'? If you get an error, post the exact error. A picture of your code is useless.